# Blackbody radiation and photons in a cavity

Tags: photons, thermal-radiation

Why is a consideration of a cavity filled with photons used to derive Planck's law? In other words, how is this cavity related to a blackbody of temperature T emitting radiation due to thermal/vibrational motion?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Kirchhoff's law depends on the second law of thermodynamics. The $T^4$ law was derived by Boltzmann using classical physics. The spectral distribution requires photons.

Comment: @Pieter No, what I mean is that the derivation of Planck's law always involves photons in a box (a photon gas) to find density of states, energy etc. I just don't understand why we do that. How does a photon gas have anything to do with a blackbody emitting radiation?

Comment: The radiation in a cavity is in thermal equilibrium with the walls of that cavity. They have the same temperature.

Comment: @Pieter So we are imagining that the walls are made up of blackbody material, meaning that when a photon hits the wall, it will be absorbed and then re-emitted away from the cavity? And this radiation will then be the blackbody radiation? But if that is the case, then won't the number of photons in the cavity quickly decline?

Comment: The cavity can be made of any material. The energy density in the cavity is a function of temperature. Only when there is a hole will photons be radiated away (with the blackbody spectrum), but new photons are quickly created. I still don't understand the question.

Comment: @Pieter Okay, but then why does this hole emit a blackbody spectrum? How does a blackbody and its spectrum have anything to do with a box filled with photons?

Comment: A small hole in a box is black, also when the box is made of white cardboard, just look at a box with a small hole. The hole is more black than ink, practically perfectly absorbing. It will glow with the blackbody spectrum. Cavity radiation and blackbody radiation are the same thing, with the same spectrum. This old knowledge, from Kirchhoff, way before Planck, that there exists a universal function that describes the distribution.